# How can I get new text copied from clipboard by right mouse?

Tags: java, clipboard

I'm coding a swing application, i used java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard to control system clipboard.

```
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
```

First, i set a default text. Then, i use java.awt.Robot to control right mouse to copy a new text from another file (txt, xlsx, ...), i have to use robot inside while loop cause my file has a lot of line

```
Robot r = new Robot();
while (line != null) {
    StringSelection contents = new StringSelection(line);
    clipboard.setContents(contents, null);

    r.mouseMove(Integer.valueOf(jTextField3.getText()), Integer.valueOf(jTextField4.getText()));
    r.mousePress(right);
    Thread.sleep(Integer.valueOf(jTextField19.getText()));
    r.mouseRelease(right);
    Thread.sleep(Integer.valueOf(jTextField19.getText()));

    Transferable t = clipboard.getContents( null );
    String data = (String)t.getTransferData( DataFlavor.stringFlavor );
    System.out.println( "Clipboard contents: " + data );
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(application.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

I try to ctrl + V to notepad, it's new text. But there's old text in console.
How can I get new text from clipboard in application?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about what the problem is?  Does the problem only occur when using the robot?  (Does it work fine otherwise?)  Does the problem only occur when you copy text while the program is running (does it work fine if the clipboard has text before the program starts)?  Can you give us a minimal but executable example and a step-by-step procedure to cause the error?

Comment: @markspace i edited my question, when i use robot outside while loop, it's OK. But when i use robot inside while loop, i can't get new text

Comment: So in a nutshell...you want to dump everything in a text file into NotePad. Is that correct?

Comment: @DevilsHnd no, i want to use new text in Application, I just tried it on notepad to see if the new text was copied

Comment: Every time you supply some information it just raises even more questions. What is `new text` to you? Is that the text that was sent to clipboard? By the term `Application`, do you mean your own Java Application and if so...why are you using Robot? And, why are you using clipboard at all? Can't you just read the file and add the file data directly to the Text Component within your application? Or is this homework and the instructor wants to to play with the Robot class?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some methods you can try:

```
public void copyStringToClipboard(String string) {
    // This represents a cut/copy (Ctrl+X/Ctrl+C) operation.
    // The text will be copied to the clipboard
    // StringSelection is a Transferable implementation
    // class.
    java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection data = new java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection(string);
    System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");
    java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard cb = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    cb.setContents(data, data);
}

public String getStringFromClipboard() {
    System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");
    // This represents the paste (Ctrl+V) operation
    java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard cb = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    try {
        if (java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor.stringFlavor == null) {
            return "";
        }
        java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable t = cb.getContents(null);
        if (t.isDataFlavorSupported(java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {
            return t.getTransferData(java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor.stringFlavor).toString();
        }
    }
    catch (java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException | java.io.IOException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("getStringFromClipboard()")
                .log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return "";
}
```

Here is an example of how to take a text file. Read it into a String, store it into the **Clipboard**, open an instance of `NotePad.exe`, set Focus on that instance of NotePad, then use **Robot** to apply a **CTRL-V** which ultimately pastes the contents held within the clipboard into the NotePad text area. **Maybe** you can get something from the process. It's all housed in one method but you will need the [**jnativehook-2.x.x** library](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.1stleg/jnativehook/2.1.0/source-code) to set focus on the NotePad window. Here is the method:

```
/**
 * Requires the JNativeHook v2.x.x Library (jar) in order to set focus onto 
 * the newly started NotePad window. Also Requires the Robot class to supply 
 * keystrokes to NotePad (like: CTRL-V to paste from clipboard).
 * 
 * The supplied file is read and appended to a StringBuilder object until 
 * the file is completely read. The String now held in the StringBuilder 
 * is copied to the clipboard. An Instance of NotePad.exe is automatically 
 * started, focus is set upon it then we let Robot enter a CTRL-V in NotePad
 * to Paste the file data held in the Clipboard into it.
 * 
 * @param filePath (String) the file path to the text file you want the 
 * contents of to be placed into NotePad.
 */
public void copyFileDataAndPasteToNotePAD(String filePath) {
    javax.swing.SwingWorker worker = new javax.swing.SwingWorker() {
        // Method to do the work
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
            File file = new File(new File(filePath).getAbsolutePath());
            if (!file.exists()) {
                System.err.println("copyFileDataAndPasteToNotePAD() Method Error! Source File Could Not Be Found!");
                System.err.println("(" + file.getAbsolutePath() + ")");
                return null;
            }
            try (java.util.Scanner reader = new Scanner(file)) {
                String line;
                while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
                    sb.append(reader.nextLine()).append(System.lineSeparator());
                }
            }
            
            try {
                java.awt.Robot robot = new java.awt.Robot();
                copyStringToClipboard(sb.toString());
                
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe");
                
                int state = com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32.SW_SHOWNORMAL;
                com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32 user32 = com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32.INSTANCE;
                com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND hWnd = user32.FindWindow(null, "Untitled - Notepad");
                if (user32.IsWindowVisible(hWnd)) {
                    user32.ShowWindow(hWnd, state); //.SW_SHOW); 
                    user32.SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
                    user32.SetFocus(hWnd);
                }
                
                //setFocusToWindowsApp("Untitled - Notepad");
                Thread.sleep(500);
                robot.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                robot.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_V);
                // You NEED to now release the Control Key!!! This is a MUST!
                robot.keyRelease(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                //robot.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            }
            catch (java.awt.AWTException | InterruptedException ex) {
                System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
            return "Task Completed";
        }
        
        // Method
        @Override
        protected void process(List chunks) {
            // define what the event dispatch thread
            // will do with the intermediate results
            // received while the thread is executing
            int val = (int) chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1);
            System.out.println("Chunks Remaining = " + val);
        }
        
        // Method
        @Override
        protected void done() {
            // this method is called when the background
            // thread finishes execution
            try {
                if (get() == null) {
                    System.out.println("JOB CANCELED!");
                }
                else {
                    String statusMsg = get().toString();
                    System.out.println("JOB COMPLETE!");
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException | java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            finally {
                this.cancel(true);
            }
        }
    };
    // Executes the swingworker on worker thread
    worker.execute();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I tried your way but it didn't work.
I tried moving the above code from jbuttonActionPerformed into main function, it actually worked, but if I put it in main function, I can't use button in application. I don't know how to explain, i recorded my trouble.
You can see my code here: https://gitlab.com/mrant.itcp/autoclick.git

Comment: @AntNguyen, Just so you know, neither clipboard code in the `main()` method or in the ActionPerformed event for the Start button worked, both produced Exceptions. To start with...comment out the clipboard related code within the `main()` method( /*....*/). Just use what is in the Start button ActionPerformed event. In code, change this: `c.setContents(contents, null);` to this: `c.setContents(contents, contents);`. This allows for some sort of owner to be established for the content in clipboard. Try your application now. As for Robot tasks, I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: You should try to place your code into a worker thread rather than running it on the EDT. You will also need to be careful with your Robot tasks...it can take over your system to the point where you won't be able to access anything. It would be a good idea to comment related code to Robot until you have your clipboard dilemma solved.

Comment: i tried c.setContents(contents, contents); but it didn't work. Maybe I have to try another ways, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard(); doesn't seem to be useful in handling this copy between application and external files into clipboard